# Differentiating an integral

Tags: calculus, functions

Let us consider a function $f$ which is continuous and differentiable in the interval $[a,b]$

If we integrate $f$ we get a graph which is continuous and differentiable in the same interval. Let us call this function $g$.

Now,if we were to differentiate $g$ would it give us the same exact graph as $f$?
What about at the endpoints of the concerned domain? Would $f$ and integral of $g$ be the same at those points as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have some function $f'(x)$, and is continuous and differentiable in the domain $[a,b]$. (Note that f'(x) need not be differentiable, as long is it is continuous and by extension Riemann integrable.)
If we integrate the function we get $f(x)+c$. If we then differentiate the constant factor becomes $0$, once again yielding $f'(x)$. Thus, all properties for the original function hold within this domain $[a,b]$, and the beginning and ending functions are the same. The values of $a$ and $b$ may differ between $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$... take $f'(x) = \cos(x)$ for example, on the range $[0,\pi]$. $f'(x)$ has values of $1$ and $-1$ at $a$ and $b$ respectively. However, $f(x) = \sin(x) + c$, and thus $f(x)$ has values of $c$ for both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $f'$ need not be differentiable..only continuous so that is it riemann integrable.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter true, but the OP specifically stated differentiable, so I included this. This is a good point however.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe just add that this is indeed not necessary in your answer? I'll delete my comments shortly thereafter

Comment: isn't a function differentiable in the open interval (a,b)?

Comment: as per my limited understanding, when we graph the derivative of a function we plot the values of the derivative at each x to get the resulting graph, butsince the function is only right differentiable at one endpoint and left differentiable at he other,we cant plot those particular points, where am i mistaken in this?

Comment: @DaipayanMukherjee That assumes that we are graphing the derivative or antiderivative using a finite amount of points, but any domain $[a,b]$ where $a \neq b$ has an infinite amount of points

Comment: sorry if i sound repetitive but i am having a problem getting this,
If i were to dfifferentiate the graph of g ,at the endpoints the graph woudl not be differentiable,i,e it would be differentiable in the open interval (a.b) .. hence the graph of derivative of g wouldnt be defined at these two points.

Comment: @DaipayanMukherjee There are infinite points to use, so the derivative has infinite points as well... none are lost in this process. Say you are trying to calculate the derivative at $0$. We then choose a point $e$ near $0$. We can calculate the derivative between these points, and we can always find some point closer to $0$ than $e$ due to the infinitude of points between any two real numbers, and the calculate the derivative between those points. Since we can make this point arbitrarily close to $0$ we can get the derivative at $0$. This isnt a rigorous proof, but I hope it makes some sense.

Comment: @DaipayanMukherjee What I am doing here is very similar to the way we calculate limits using the definition of the limit... I recommend looking into it if you haven't already. It is basically the same thing I am saying here, but in a much more rigorous manner (you can apply the same rigour here, but I am limited by the amount of characters and formatting in the comment section)